# How to check first 2characters of String in Android

Tags: java, android

In my application, I want to get a phone number from the user and if the first **2 characters** of this number are **09**, I want to show `Toast`.
I wrote the code below, but it always shows me the `Toast` message.
**My code:**

```
    phoneNumberPage_phoneEdtTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().length() < 11) {
                enableDisableBtn(0.3f, false);
            } else {
                hideKeyboard(activity);
                enableDisableBtn(1.0f, true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.toString().trim().length()==1){
                if (!s.equals("0")){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "NOOOOOO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

How can I do it? Can you please help me?

Comment: you can use `startsWith` method.

Comment: the toast will appear when you enter everything else than 0.

Comment: @MustafaÇil, how can i it? can you help me and send to me code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using **startsWith**

```
if(s.startsWith("09")){
```

or you can use **matches** with regex

```
if(s.matches("09(.*)"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check [String reference especially substring method](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)). In your case you can use substring like this:

```
String twoFirstCharacters = string.substring(0, 2);
if (twoFirstCharacters.equals("09")) {
    // here we go
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use String.startsWith() method

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
     if (s!=null&& !s.toString().trim().isEmpty()){ // make sure String value is there
      if (!s.startsWith("09")){ // check string qualifies your requirement 
              Toast.makeText(context, "NOOOOOO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
      }
}
```